# How to manage a list of foreign keys in a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, iterator, foreign-keys

I am using Sqlite3.

I have a table, 'Team', which has a nullable list of 'Player's.

Each 'Player' is a unique id which is a foreign key to another table 'Player'.

Each 'Team' can have a max of 10 'Player's.

Each 'Player' is named like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
"Team"
"("
"TeamID varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,"
"UserID varchar(64) NOT NULL,"
"League varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
"PlayerID_1 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_2 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_3 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_4 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_5 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_6 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_7 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_8 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_9 varchar(64),"
"PlayerID_10 varchar(64),"
"FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_1) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_2) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_3) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_4) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_5) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_6) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_7) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_8) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_9) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
"FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID_10) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID)"
");";
```

My question is, how can I easily insert a new 'Player' into the table? I need a way to iterate over each current 'Player' in the table, to find the first NULL column.

I am interfacing with this db from C, and it wouldn't be so hard to get the table into memory with a query, iterate over it in memory to find the first NULL 'Player', and insert the new one there, but that seems extremely inefficient!

Also, if this is design is bad, please feel free to propose a better one! I am still pretty new to db design.

Comment: Yes, this design is bad. player[[xyz] is basically an array, and so are the FKs. In modeling language: it is a **repeating group**. The same constrants apply for player1 ... player10, and you'll have to duplicate them. Also: how would you avoid that player1 <> player2, etcetera? [45 contraints ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use that design, it would be better if you normalize your tables so that you have the "Player" table reference the "Team" table to tell which team a given player belongs to.

Then, adding a new player to a team is a matter of just adding a new row to the "Player" table.

It's also easier to make a player switch teams, or even remove a player.

You can control the limit of 10 players per team from your application (check how many players the team already has before adding a new one).

Or you can create a trigger that will raise an error if adding a row to the Player table results in more than 10 players in a team.

```
 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
 "Team"
 "("
 "TeamID varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,"
 "UserID varchar(64) NOT NULL,"
 "League varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
 "FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID)"
 ");";

 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
 "Player"
 "("
 "PlayerID varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,"
 "TeamID varchar(64) NOT NULL,"
 "PlayerName varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
 "FOREIGN KEY (TeamID) REFERENCES Team(TeamID)"
 ");";
```

**EDIT**

If the same player can be in multiple teams, then you need a third table to map Players to Teams.

Then, each player can exist only once, but then you can map the same player to multiple teams by adding multiple rows in the "PlayerToTeam" table.

Something like this:

```
 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
 "Team"
 "("
 "TeamID varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,"
 "UserID varchar(64) NOT NULL,"
 "League varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
 "FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID)"
 ");";

 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
 "Player"
 "("
 "PlayerID varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,"
 "PlayerName varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
 ");";

 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
 "PlayerToTeam"
 "("
 "PlayerID varchar(64) NOT NULL,"
 "TeamID varchar(64) NOT NULL,"
 "PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID, TeamID),"
 "FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES Player(PlayerID),"
 "FOREIGN KEY (TeamID) REFERENCES Team(TeamID)"
 ");";
```

Comment: If each User can have multiple Teams, and some Teams will share the same Players, wouldn't that be redundant? I'd need to create a new Player for each and every Team, so if 5 Users have the same Player, I'd need 5 copies of the same one, just with a different Foreign Key. They could all have the same PlayerID though.

Comment: I didn't think the same player would be in different teams. I added a second part to my answer to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks! This is a much better design. As I said, I'm rather new to designing db schemas, the go between of Player<--PlayerToTeam-->Team is really helpful, since I was going to have this same issue on several other tables. Thanks again!